# .htaccess: How do I beautify my URL and remove the trailing forwardslash?

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, deployment

Just trying to access my site without a trailing forwardslash. I have an app that lives nested in a wordpress install at:

```
mysite.com/My-App/
```

I need to access it with lowercases and without a trailing forwardslash, like this:

```
mysite.com/my-app
```

Here is my current .htaccess. As you can see I've been trying to figure it out but can't seem to get it to work.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^My-App/$ My-App/public/
RewriteRule ^my-app$ My-App/

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

To remove a trailing slash using .htaccess all you need to use is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

This will leave you with the URL: `mysite.com/my-app`. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but based on the .htaccess file I posted this solution doesn't work...